# Pandas to Parquet with per-column compression

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) marks the following:

> **compression**: str or None, default ‘snappy’
>
> Name of the compression to use. Use None for no compression. Supported options: ‘snappy’, ‘gzip’, ‘brotli’, ‘lz4’, ‘zstd’.

In the [arrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html), they state the per-column compression:

> **compression**: str or dict
>
> Specify the compression codec, either on a general basis or per-column. Valid values: {‘NONE’, ‘SNAPPY’, ‘GZIP’, ‘BROTLI’, ‘LZ4’,‘ZSTD’}.

As you can see, it seems from the documentation that it's not implemented. Has anyone tried it and make work pandas with parket per-column compression? Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `compression` parameter in `to_parquet` is intended for specifying the compression algorithm for the entire file, not on a per-column basis.

The Parquet format itself supports per-column compression, but whether it is exposed through the pandas interface is another matter.

At the moment the `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet` method is not directly supported.

The most similar issue open question is actually [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55571) one, but it differs from your question

Comment: Interesting. Does it mean that the compression in pandas is the standard parquet compression or not? Because if it's not, that means that the interest of per-column format is loss (since you might have to decompress before loading).